# Pourquoi n'a-t-on pas laissé le « que » ici ?

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées

> « Tu te rends compte, il aurait pu t’arriver n’importe quoi ! Tu es complètement inconsciente ! »

Pourquoi ce n’est pas « Tu te rends compte **qu**’il aurait pu t’arriver... » ?

C’est juste une façon de parler ou il y a une raison grammaticale ?

Answer (score 5):

Les deux expressions sont correctes.

Dans la première, *tu te rends compte* est d'abord autonome et signifie :

> Tu as conscience de ce que tu as fait !
>   Tu réalises ce que tu as fait !

Les deux propositions sont indépendantes (juxtaposées) alors que dans la deuxième, il y a dépendance (propositions principale et subordonnée) et la signification est immédiatement restreinte :

> Tu as conscience qu'il aurait pu t’arriver n’importe quoi !
>   Tu réalises qu'il aurait pu t’arriver n’importe quoi !

Answer (score 1):

Dans la phrase:

1)
 **« Tu te rends compte, il aurait pu t’arriver n’importe quoi !Tu es complètement inconsciente ! »**

Il y a simplement le "style" de l'auteur pour la ponctuation de son dialogue.

S'il avait écrit:

2)
**« Tu te rends compte? Il aurait pu t’arriver n’importe quoi ! Tu es complètement inconsciente ! »**,

**Les phrases seraient dites** de la même façon. Les pauses introduites (par un acteur ou locuteur, par exemple) seraient les mêmes.

La phrase [1)] fait partie d'un dialogue. Dans les deux cas, elles seraient prononcées (dites) de la même façon malgré la ponctuation. L'auteur (à mon avis) aurait dû faire deux phrases. **Ici, la question n'est pas tant grammaticale que rédactionelle.**

Donc, je pense qu'on est en présence d'une faute de ponctuation. Un bon réviseur aurait coupé la phrase en deux. Mais, avec le phénomène de "l'auto-édition" et l'Internet, les auteurs se précipitent sans trop faire attention aux détails.

**Par ailleurs, la phrase: « Tu te rends compte ? », phrase interrogative,  s'entend tout le temps dans le français parlé.** Elle sert d'introduction à la problématique qui va suivre. Par exemple: « Tu te rends compte ?  Ce gars est parti avec ton vélo! »